# The proof of the product of two continuous functions is also a continuous function in multivariable case.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I want to show that the the product rule of continuous function can be extend to the multivariable case.

So, by my setting, given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are both continuous function defined over $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, now let function $h(x,y)$ be a function with two variable over $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $h(x)=f(x)⋅g(y)$, which is the product of $f(x)$ and $g(y)$.
My purpose is to prove this new two variable function $h(x)=f(x)⋅g(y)$ satisfied the continuity definition, which is, $\forall$ $x$ and $y$, and  $\forall$ $a$ and $b$ in the domain, there exist a $\delta$ such that$ \sqrt{(x − a)^2 + (y − b)^2}< δ$, so that $\left|h(x,y)-h(a,b)\right|<\epsilon$.

So what I am think at here is following, let $\epsilon>0 $ be given.
I want to show

$$\left|f(x)g(y)-f(a)g(b)\right|<\epsilon$$

Since we know the function $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are both continuous, than for all $x$ and $y$, we have $\left|x-a\right|<\delta$ and $\left|y-b\right|<\delta$, then
$$\left|f(x)-f(a)\right|<\epsilon, and\; \left|g(x)-g(a)\right|<\epsilon $$

I am guess I need to rearrange this part $f(x)g(y)-f(a)g(b)$, so that I could plugin $\left|f(x)-f(a)\right|<\epsilon$, and $\left|g(x)-g(a)\right|<\epsilon$ into it and obtain some a bound for $\delta$, but I have trouble at here, I was trying to add and sub subtract something like $f(x)g(b)$, but none of them work, could someone give me some hint on the algebraic operation at here

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Prove that multiplication $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, then use the fact that composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: @stackex33 I am confuse at here, so the product of two function with respect to different variable should be treat as composition?

Comment: No, by composition I meant $(x, y)\mapsto (f(x), g(y))\mapsto f(x)g(y)$. The first function is continuous because $f, g$ are continuous.